# PHP & Apache - chown() using Apache owner:group?

Tags: php, apache

I'm creating tests for an application that has 3 environments: dev, staging, and production.

I want to run a test which programmatically pulls the default apache owner and group (from httpd.conf), and checks to make sure the uploads directory is owned by this same owner/group combo.

Is there a PHP function that is capable of pulling this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the PHP script below.

Don't forget to change the input data for your setup:

**$apacheEnvVarsConfFile** - the apache conf file that defines the user to be used; in this example it was /etc/apache2/envvars and the line defining it was export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data

**$dirThatYouWantToTest** - the directory for which you want to read the user/group permissions

```
<?php

## define input data
$apacheEnvVarsConfFile = '/etc/apache2/envvars';
$dirThatYouWantToTest = '/var/www';

## compute the information that is needed
$data = array();

$data['apacheUser'] = str_replace('export APACHE_RUN_USER=', '', exec('cat '.$apacheEnvVarsConfFile.' | grep APACHE_RUN_USER'));

$dirStat = stat($dirThatYouWantToTest);
$data['dirTested'] = $dirThatYouWantToTest;
$data['dirUser'] = posix_getpwuid($dirStat[4])['name'];
$data['dirGroup'] = posix_getgrgid($dirStat[5])['name'];
$data['dirPerms'] = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($dirThatYouWantToTest)), -4);

echo '<pre>';print_r( $data );echo '</pre>';

## the code above will produce the following output (example): 
/*
Array
(
    [apacheUser] => www-data
    [dirTested] => /var/www
    [dirUser] => john
    [dirGroup] => john
    [dirPerms] => 0755
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends under what permissions the php script runs. if it runs as the default apache user, it can. Use any php function that reads a file like file_get_contents or [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

However if the php thread doesn not have access to the apache folder (e.g runs under different permissions) then it is tricky to fetch the data. In a sense you will have to hack the apache through php. But since you own the server, you can just make php change user or call an extenral script (which will run under other permisions) and get the data through the external script